# Prove that the Upper Lebesgue Sum matches with the Lebesgue Integral when $\mu(X)$ and $|f|$ $< \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

$\textbf{Question}$: Suppose $(X,S,\mu)$ is a measure space with $\mu(X)<\infty$. Suppose $f:X \to [0,\infty)$ is a bounded $S$-measureable function. Prove that $\int f d\mu = \inf\{\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^m \mu(A_j)\sup_{A_j}f: A_1, ..., A_m $$\text{ is an $S\ $ partition}\}$

$\textbf{Attempt}$: $f$ being bounded, we can get an interval $[a,b]$ such that $f(X)\subset [a,b]$ where $a=\inf f$ and $b=\sup f$. Now, let us consider the family of intervals $\{[a,a+\epsilon),[a+\epsilon,a+2\epsilon),...,[a+(n-1)\epsilon,a+n\epsilon)\}$ where $\epsilon>0$ is small and $n$ is chosen such that the union $\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^n[a+(i-1)\epsilon,a+i\epsilon)\supset [a,b]$.
Now, $f$ being an $S$ measureable function, $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^n$ defined by $A_i=f^{-1}([a+(i-1)\epsilon,a+i\epsilon))$ constitutes an $S$ partition of $X$.

Evidently, $\displaystyle\sup_{A_i} f-\inf_{A_i}f\leq \epsilon$ for each $i$. Therefore, we end up with $\displaystyle0\leq\sum_{j=1}^n \mu(A_j)\sup_{A_j}f-\int f d\mu\leq\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^n \mu(A_j)\sup_{A_j}f-\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^n \mu(A_j)\inf_{A_j}f\leq \epsilon \mu(X)$.

As $\mu(X)<\infty$ we can do $\displaystyle\epsilon \mapsto \frac{\epsilon}{\mu(X)}$, and henceforth we conclude that:
$\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists$ an $S$ partition $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^n$ such that $\displaystyle0\leq\sum_{j=1}^n \mu(A_j)\sup_{A_j}f-\int f d\mu\leq \epsilon$, which establishes the required statement.

[Note: The leftmost inequality of the previous line can be justified as this: For any simple function $\displaystyle\phi(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sup_{A_i}f \ \chi_{A_i}(x)$, $\{A_i\}$ being an $S$ partition, we have $\phi\geq f$ on $X$, so $\int \phi= \sum_{j=1}^n \mu(A_j)\sup_{A_j}f \geq \int f$. ]

*Verification Requested.*

Comment: Your $n$ depends on $\varepsilon$, so your estimate is invalid. I think you meant to say $$\sum_{j=1}^n \mu(A_j)\sup_{A_j}f - \sum_{j=1}^n \mu(A_j)\inf_{A_j}f \leq \epsilon \mu(X).$$ Other than this the proof looks correct.

Comment: @Mason, Thanks for pointing it out, indeed I meant to say what you wrote above. I'll edit it.